# How to escape from ORMs limitations or should I avoid them?

Tags: entity-framework, orm, business-logic, software-design

### In short, ORMs like Entity Framework provides a fast solution but with many limitations, When should they (ORMs) be avoided?

I want to create an engine of a DMS system, I wonder that how could I create the Business Logic Layer.

I'll discuss the following options:

- Using Entity Framework and provides it as a Business later for the engine's clients.

  **The problem** is that missing the control on the properties and the validation because it's generated code.
- Create my own business layer classes manually without using Entity Framework or any ORM:

  **The problem** is that it's a hard mission and something like reinvent the weel.
- Create my own business layer classes up on the Entitiy Framework (use it)

  **The problem** Seems to be code repeating by creating new classes with the same names and every property will cover the opposite one which is generated by the ORM.

Am I discuss the problem in a right way?

Answer (score 4):

In short, ORMs should be avoided when:

- your program will perform bulk inserts/updates/deletes (such as insert-selects, and updates/deletes that are conditional on something non-unique). ORMs are not designed to do these kinds of bulk operations efficiently; you will end up deleting each record one at a time.
- you are using highly custom data types or conversions. ORMs are generally bad at dealing with BLOBs, and there are limits to how they can be told how to "map" objects.
- you need the absolute highest performance in your communication with SQL Server. ORMs can suffer from N+1 problems and other query inefficiencies, and overall they add a layer of (usually reflective) translation between your request for an object and a SQL statement which will slow you down.

ORMs should instead be used in most cases of application-based record maintenance, where the user is viewing aggregated results and/or updating individual records, consisting of simple data types, one at a time. ORMs have the extreme advantage over raw SQL in their ability to provide compiler-checked queries using Linq providers; virtually all of the popular ORMs (Linq2SQL, EF, NHibernate, Azure) have a Linq query interface that can catch a lot of "fat fingers" and other common mistakes in queries that you don't catch when using "magic strings" to form SQLCommands. ORMs also generally provide database independence. Classic NHibernate HBM mappings are XML files, which can be swapped out as necessary to point the repository at MSS, Oracle, SQLite, Postgres, and other RDBMSes. Even "fluent" mappings, which are classes in code files, can be swapped out if correctly architected. EF has similar functionality.

Comment: You've metioned `application-based record maintenance`. But actually I wonder if it's OK to use ORM's as a BBL in an engine (no UI provided)

Comment: As long as you're saving one record at a time, ORMs generally don't slow these kinds of processes down enough to be a major concern in batch processes; there's often something much slower in the process, like simply querying over a network. I normally see ORM-based DALs in ETL-type processes when you already have a domain model and DAL from a user app; it saves you a lot of time just architecting the ETL to use your existing DAL than to write one from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

So are you asking how to do "X" without doing "X"? ORM is an abstraction and as any other abstraction it has disadvantages but not those you mentioned.

- Code (EFv4) can be generated by T4 template and T4 template is a code that can be modified
- Generated code is partial class which can be combined with your partial part containing your logic
- Writing classes manually is very common case - using designer as available in Entity framework is more rare

Comment: Actually I've mentioned "Am I discuss the problem in a right way" because I'm not sure that I'm discuessing my problem correctly.

Comment: The problem which I'm not sure about is that is using ORMs misses the control over the whole layer if I provide the context for the engine's client?. That is my problem.

Comment: You are partially losing control over database queries generated by ORM and the way how ORM interacts with database but you are not loosing control over business logic.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** I work at Mindscape that builds the LightSpeed ORM for .NET

As you don't ask about a specific issue, but about approaches to solving the flexibility problem with an ORM I thought I'd chime in with some views from a vendor perspective. It may or may not be of use to you but might give some food for thought :-)

When designing an O/R Mapper it's important to take into consideration what we call "escape hatches". An ORM will inevitably push a certain set of default behaviours which is one way that developer gain productivity gains.

One of the lessons we have learned with LightSpeed has been where developers need those escape hatches. For example, KeithS here states that ORMs are not good for bulk operations - and in most cases this is true. We had this scenario come up with some customers and added an overload to our Remove() operation that allowed you to pass in a query that removes all records that match. This saved having to load entities into memory and delete them. Listening to where developers are having pain and helping solve those problems quickly is important for helping build solid solutions.

All ORMs should efficiently batch queries. Having said that, we have been surprised to see that many ORMs don't. This is strange given that often batching can be done rather easily and several queries can be bundled up and sent to the database at once to save round trips. This is something we've done since day 1 for any database that supports it. That's just an aside to the point of batching made in this thread. The quality of those batches queries is the real challenge and, frankly, there are some TERRIBLE SQL statements being generated by some ORMs.

Overall you should select an ORM that gives you immediate productivity gains (almost demo-ware styled 'see I queried data in 30s!') but has also paid attention to larger scale solutions which is where escape hatches and some of the less demoed, but hugely useful features are needed.

I hope this post hasn't come across too salesy, but I wanted to draw attention to taking into account the thought process that goes behind any product when selecting it. If the philosophy matches the way you need to work then you're probably going to be happier than selecting one that does not.

If you're interested, you can learn about our [LightSpeed ORM for .NET](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/lightspeed).

Answer (score -1):

in my experience you should avoid use ORM when your application do the following data manipulation:

1)Bulk deletes: most of the ORM tools wont truly delete the data, they will mark it with a garbage collect ID (GC record) to keep the database consistency. The worst thing is that the ORM collect all the data you want to delete before it mark it as deleted. That means that if you want to delete 1000000 rows the ORM will first fetch the data, load it in your application, mark it as GC and then update the database;. which I believe is a huge waist of resources.

2)bulk inserts and data import:most of the ORM tools will create business layer validations on the business classes, this is good if you want to validate 1 record but if you are going to insert/import hundreds or even millions of records the process could take days.

3)Report generation: the ORM tools are good to create simple list reports or simple table joins like in a order-order_details scenario. but it most cases the ORM will only slow down the retrieve of the data and will add more joins that you need for a report. that translate in a give more work to the DB engine than you usually do with a SQL approach

Comment: I must comment this: "...but if you are going to insert/import hundreds or even millions of records the process could take days..." A few days ago I have programmed a data import with EF 4.1 for a file with 550.000 records into a table (not very complex, only 8 columns): The import took 3 minutes with a locally installed SQL Server 2008 Express.

Comment: well... you might be right, do you have a benchmark to insert the same amount of records with direct SQL?

Comment: and I think I forgot to talk about this, the speed in the ORM usage will depend on how the business classes are design. The process will be slower if you  have validations within the class.

Comment: No, I don't have a benchmark for direct SQL import. (But I have no doubt that it will be faster.) And I don't have validations within the class. My critic was mainly against your extreme time span ("process could take *days*") which doesn't look like a well-founded estimation in my experience.

Comment: yeah your right I think I over reacted, I remember long time ago I upload about 90 millions of records(from phone calls) in a db and it took me 3 or 4 days, I guess it was simple to much data and the network, and hardware was just not enough.